# Creating a sub domain to rank in google search carousal

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, penalty

i manage a media/news website. It was hit by google penalty in the past, due to which we never get featured in google search carousal listing again. our website primary is in English.

I have a sub directory which cover other language i.e. Hindi. This section is entirely different from the main website. Meaning it covers different stories than the primary website.

Now my question is, Does moving the sub directory to new subdomain will help us get featured in Search Carousal Listing.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's media/news website, i presume when you says "Search Carousel Listing" that you mean "Google News"? Carousel is used for [some other data types](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel).

If that is the case, then moving it to a sub directory can help, because, when you apply for [inclusion of your website to Google News](https://support.google.com/news/publisher-center/answer/7526416?hl=en&ref_topic=9010462#), one of the technical requirements is that "news" pages are clearly identified, so your sub directory (i.e. /news-hindi/) would help in that case.